# $(window).height() reports wrong height in IE8 (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code below. IE8 displays a smaller height. The difference is over 100 pixels. It works fine in FireFox. Why doesn't it work right in IE?

```
<html>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       window.onresize = ff;

    function ff()
    {
     window.status = jQuery(window).height() ;
     }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify a doctype? Usually things of this nature are more consistent in standards mode, whereas in quirksmode anything goes.

Comment: The "Developer Tools" show what mode the browser is using, and lets you change it dynamically. (mentioned for the benefit of interested readers)

Comment: You can also do `javascript:alert( document.compatMode )` in the address bar. CSS1Compat is what you want. If you don't see it, throw a doctype in.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. The browser had zoom turned on to 125%!